# Copying JNLP app to computer lacking Internet access

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

How might I go about running a JNLP app on a machine that has no Internet access?  Is there a way to copy the app's files from a machine where the app has already been downloaded and run?

Comment: You can use `file:///` URLs in JNLP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A project named [jnlpdownloader](http://code.google.com/p/jnlpdownloader/) does this task, download from the jnlp all dependencies and creates executables.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to request a .jar file download that you can run with `java -jar program.jar` because the files that are stored after the launch of the .jnlp isn't really "readable", you will find that resources and classes names are somewhat obfuscated.

Comment: I got curious and looked for them , they are stored in {USER_HOME}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment